# What to do with closed but upvoted off-topic questions with no answers?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, clean-up, unanswered-questions

I'd like to have guidance on the value of old questions closed as off-topic with no answers:

- 6,708 such questions as of Jan 4 2019: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=closed%3A1+duplicate%3A0+locked%3A0+answers%3A0+created%3A..1y

Being closed, there won't ever be any *answer* given to those off-topic questions.

Note that there is already a [roomba](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba) rule, `RemoveAbandonedClosed`, that takes care of closed questions with no answers **and a score of 0 or less**. So this discussion is essentially about upvoted off-topic questions (score 1 or higher) with no answers.

Should we reopen some of them?
Should we delete some of them?
Should we leave them as is?

Comment: Quite a few of those have a score less than 1. Roomba is missing some corners.

Comment: @PaulCrovella multiple possibilities: post is locked, post was undeleted, downvote is less than a week old, etc.

Comment: I don't see much value in these. Reopen any that should be open, delete the rest. Hell, with almost 7k to go through I don't mind throwing out babies with the bath water on this stuff, nuke the lot of 'em. They exist just to collect complaints in the comments.

Comment: If the consensus is that deletion is the right choice, maybe we should ask - *why* are said questions immune from the roomba?

Comment: Time for the "Off-topic with no answers" review queue!

Comment: @Nick As if the current review queues are all doing well!

Comment: `Being closed, there won't ever be any answer given to those off-topic questions.` That's not necessarily true; any question can be reopened at any time if 5 users vote to reopen it, at which point it can then be answered.

Comment: @Cœur The answer is obviously yes we should do one of those three things for each of these. This question is too broad in it's current form.

Comment: @TylerH If something's intrinsically off-topic (e.g. General Computing, blatantly off-topic, recommendation request, etc.), then the questions will *never* be re-opened unless the OP either completely rewrites the question to be something unrelated (which they shouldn't do) or there's a change in site rules to start accepting those kinds of questions again (which is unlikely).

Comment: @TylerH One other point: if something's been closed for, say, a year or more, what are the odds that someone's going to edit it into shape that long after the fact? How often does that actually happen?

Comment: @EJoshuaS Yes, but OP included all close reasons except for Duplicate in their parameters, not just intrinsically off-topic ones, so that is a strawman argument. As for your second comment, I don't have any exact numbers but I know it happens occasionally. You should run a SEDE query to find out exactly how often it happens!

Comment: Looking at the top ones, the first one about firebase seems legit, just badly worded. It even has an answer from the developer in the comments.

Comment: 1. Get fire. 2. Apply fire to questions. 3. ??? 4. Watch bonfire.

Answer (score 6):

Only two options that I see going forward (none of which can be directly motivated by the community):

- Create a new review queue for questions like these.  If the system resists deleting them, show them to the community to determine if they really *do* have any worth.
- Strengthen the Roomba for this case.  If these questions aren't getting the attention they should and are left to languish in purgatory for all of time, then the system should be smart enough to purge them.

Comment: "Create a new review queue for questions like these."  We already have the reopen queue.  If the question has already been "leave closed" by that queue, it's already been determined to not merit reopening.  If you wanted to determine if they've been fixed since, you'd only really need to come up with some new criteria to put them in the queue, rather than needing a new one.

Comment: @Servy:  Reopen queue only determines if the question should be *reopened*.  I'm thinking that this queue should determine if the question should be *deleted*.  As far as I'm aware the other queues which *can* handle question/answer deletion wouldn't register any of these questions since the score is too high.  Furthermore, context matters; the context is that we want to see if these questions have value, not if they should be reopened or not.  Some closed questions *still* add value to the site.

Comment: Outside of the potential for being improved in the future in order to become answerable, what value is an unanswered closed question going to have?

Comment: We're getting into the mechanics of how a review queue like this *could* work now.  If there *is* value to be found, then great - reopen it immediately.  Someone could then provide an answer for it.  Maybe even announce it more prominently for a time (weaker than a bounty).  If it would have otherwise qualified as an "abandoned" question, then once that period elapses, immediately delete the question as the "value" there was a false positive.

Comment: So you're asking people to check if the question now merits reopening.  That's what the reopen queue does.  Just send the question though the queue again when it's a year old (or whatever criteria is chosen), if it passes, it's now open, if it fails it went a whole year without getting fixed, it's not likely to get fixed anymore, so delete it.

Comment: ...which is why it justifies creating a new queue for it.  There is **context** to be had here.  The queues as they work today are a bit on the simple side and in my mind, at least, it'd make more sense to give it the Caesar-style vote rather than retrofit this logic into the Close Vote queue.

Comment: If all you're doing is checking if the question merits reopening, then *you wouldn't need to review it any differently*.  You just check if the question merits closure or not.  Whether the question is new or not wouldn't change that, only what the system does with the information you give it.  Having two queues *where you do exactly the same thing in both queues* isn't helpful, it'd just be confusing.

Comment: @Makoto a problem with an answer with two ideas (especially when they oppose each-other) is that I can't vote independently for the two ideas.